# JAX-RS: ParamConverterProvider rawType mismatch

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

In my REST application I have a `@POST` method which consumes `x-www-form-urlencoded` and produces `application/json` and is designed to create new appointments for a beauty center:

```
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public Response bookAppointment(@FormParam("date") Date appDate,
        @FormParam("time") Time appTime, @FormParam("type") String appType,
        @FormParam("clientName") String clientName, @FormParam("email") String clientEmail,
        @DefaultValue("") @FormParam("message") String clientMsg) {
    //externalize the validation of all fields to concentrate on "positive"
    //scenario only
    validator(appDate, appType, clientName, clientEmail);
    Appointment appointment = build(appDate, appTime, appType,clientName, 
                clientEmail, clientMsg);
    try {
        repository.add(appointment);
        return Response.ok(appointment).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException("Something happened in the application "
                + "and this apointment could not get saved. Please contact us "
                + "to inform us of this issue.");
    }
}
```

As you may see for two Endpoint method attributes are Java objects (`sql.Time` and `sql.Date`). To convert them from strings coming from the client I am using `ParamConverterProvider`s as taught in B. Burke's *Restful Java with JAX-RS* (p. 70-71) and this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256095/jax-rs-paramconverter-paramconverterprovider-method-return-type-mismatch).

I am using Postman chrome add-on to send requests and everything works fine and dandy if for time and date I am sending the full String required attributes for `valueOf()` builder methods of `sql.Date` and `sql.Time`(i.e. `yyyy-MM-dd` and `hh:MM:ss`, respectively). However when I am sending time without seconds I receive the 404 Exception with a generic message.

This is what I am sending from Postman:
[image]

If you will take a look at one of the `ParamConverterProvider`s you will see that I am accounting for partial user input and in either way am throwing a custom message for `BadRequestException` (which works for other validation constraints):

```
@Provider
public class SqlTimeConverterProvider implements ParamConverterProvider {
    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> rawType, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations) {
        System.out.println("SqlTimeConverterProvider");
        if (rawType.equals(Time.class)) {
            return new ParamConverter<T>() {

                @Override
                public T fromString(String value) {
                    //in case the ParamConverter does not do URI deconding
                    value = value.replaceAll("%3A", ":");
                    if (value.length() < 6) {
                        value = value.concat(":00");
                    }
                    if (!value.matches("([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]"
                            + "(:[0-5][0-9])*")) {
                        throw new BadRequestException(value + " is not an accepted Time format "
                                + "please use this pattern: hh:mm:SS");
                    }
                    return rawType.cast(Time.valueOf(value));
                }

                @Override
                public String toString(T value) {
                    Time timeRepr = (Time) value;
                    if (timeRepr.toLocalTime().getMinute() < 10) {
                        String reply = timeRepr.toLocalTime().getHour()+":"
                                +timeRepr.toLocalTime().getMinute();
                        return reply.concat("0");
                    }
                    return timeRepr.toLocalTime().toString();
                }

            };
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Interesting enough using NetBeans debugger I have discovered that after this line in the code above:

```
System.out.println("SqlTimeConverterProvider");
     if (rawType.equals(Time.class)) {
```

the 'Step over' moves the break-point to **return null** and the same thing repeats for the Date converter provider. As I am following meticulously the example from the book I am unsure as to why is the `rawType` being evaluated to false

Comment: can you do `System.out.println(rawType.getName())` before the IF?

Comment: Interesting idea which never hit my head :-| One minute please :-)

Comment: You should see a bunch of class names printed out corresponding to the types of all parameters of your method

Comment: This is the output rawType.getName()

Info:   long

Comment: Based on your post and your comments your JAX-RS implementation is already converting the String you pass into a date, that's why you see long. You probably don't need any custom converter.  Try doing this with the long value: `System.out.println(new Date(value))` within the ParamConverter

Comment: Thanks Jean-Francois, I have replaced that if comparison with rawType.isAssignableFrom(Time.class)

unfortunately the break-point jumps to return null again...I don't even understand why 'long'. I tried something ridiculous as if(rawType.getName.equals("long")) and this is evaluated to false!

Comment: Are you expecting this to work for both Time and Date, because these are different types, not within the same hierarchy. Or do you have a provider for both Date and Time?

Comment: can you place exact code with print statement in the question and the exact output please? Literally copy and paste the code and the output

Comment: Also do you realize that the getConverter will get called many times on startup to determine if this is the correct provider for a certain parameter. Most it the times it will return null, except during a pass to check for the specific Time parameter type.

Comment: Hi Ulises, in your example new Date takes a String as parameter, but it requires long. I could use valueOf, but! For that I would have to move the statement inside fromString method - my problem is not being able to get inside that method. Also I apprehend that JAX-RS automatically converts this to Java objects, but the problem then is that it throws in exception for e.g.: '11:00'. 

Peeskillet, I have different ParamConverterProviders for Time and Date. And yes, they are both called twice at start-up each.

Comment: So is this still a type mismatch problem then? Are you saying that with both passes, it returns null?

Comment: There are no passes. Theoretically I should be getting Time and Date, but I get long each time.