# Creating and injecting a per request scoped variable

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, scope

I would like to have a variable that follows along the full lifecycle of a request in java EE.
For example it could be for a logging function, so that I can filter all log entries by request.

The key part that I want to get at is that it must be relatively easy to implement in an already existing application so if possible some sort of dependency injection that gets the variable related to the specific request.

I've tried injectiong a `@RequestScoped` variable, but it doesn't work since it is only scoped to the container. I would need to be able to inject the same object to different containers. Is this at all possible?

**EDIT**: I want something along the lines of this:

```
@RequestScoped
public class RequestVariables {
    public String id;
}
@Stateless
public class Logger {
    @Inject
    private RequestVariables requestVariables;
    public void log(String message) {
        System.out.println(requestVariables.id + ":" + message);
    }   
}

@Stateless
public class Service {
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;
    @Inject
    private RequestVariables requestVariables;
    public void save(String data) {
        logger.log("Save");
        session.save(data + requestVariables.id); //Maybe add request parameter to save aswell
    }
}

public class API {
    @Inject
    private Service service;
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;
    @Inject
    private RequestVariables requestVariables;
    @Path("/1")
    @GET
    public Response get(@QueryParam("data") String data) {
        requestVariables.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        service.save(data);
        logger.log("Get");
        return Response.status(204).build();
    }
}
```

Currently this is what I have experimented with:

```
@RequestScoped
public class RequestScope {
    private int test = 0;

    public RequestScope(int test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
    public RequestScope(){}

    public int getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(int test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
@Provider
public class RequestScopeFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Inject
    private javax.inject.Provider<RequestScope> requestScopeProvider;

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        requestScopeProvider.get().setTest(42);
        request.setAttribute("test", "superTest");
    }
}

@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
@TransactionAttribute(value=TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class Service {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    @Inject
    private Provider<RequestScope> requestScopeProvider;

    public void test() {
        RequestScope scope = requestScopeProvider.get();
        String test = (String)httpServletRequest.getAttribute("test");
    }    
}
```

So when I get the scope from my service then it is a new object with `test` set to 0, and then it throws an NPE since `httpServletRequest` is null

Comment: make the Object Singleton, in Spring there is @Scope("Singleton") annotation on class level and you can also define through xml level.

Comment: @ArifMustafa but if I make it singleton, wouldn't it's state be shared between different requests?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html
Reading about Singletons there makes it seem as if the state would be shared between requests(maybe not between sessions?)

Comment: please come with the source, so we will get your condition more...

Comment: I agree with ArifMustafa, we need a better description.  For logging, a Singleton would be ideal.  You'll have to explain more what you are really trying to do.  Try to give us some code and and at least two to three use case examples.

Comment: I just updated with some mock code that hopefully shows in more detail an example of what I am after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that I found is to use ThreadLocal variables. It seems rather dirty, but it works since each request is executed on it's own thread(as far as I am aware). So this is what I got:

```
public class RequestScope {
    private static final ThreadLocal<String> id = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    public static String get() {
        return id.get();
    }
}
```

With that I can also easily exchange the `ThreadLocal` to return something more specific if so desired.
And I can get the variables from pretty much anywhere, assuming that the request is not starting a different thread

Answer (score 1):

**option #1**

Implement an Interceptor and set the request id as `HttpServletRequest` attribute:

```
@AroundInvoke
public Object setRequestId(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
    HttpServletRequest request = [..] // getHttpServletRequest(ic);
    request.setAttribute("request-id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    return ic.proceed();
}
```

Then use `HttpServletRequest` everywhere you need it

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
```

**option #2**

If want just to filter your logs by an unique id, you can configure your Logger to print the thread name: `[%t]`

Example: [Log4j PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)

**option #3**

Use a custom java bean to encapsulate the request data (query param, request id etc.) and pass this bean across your application services.

```
public class API {

    @Inject
    private Service service;

    @Path("/1")
    @GET
    public Response get(MyCustomRequestBean data) {
        service.doSomejob(data);
        return Response.status(204).build();
    }
}
```

Set the request id and query param in `ParamConverter`:

[Jax-RS ParamConverter - ParamConverterProvider method return type mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256095/jax-rs-paramconverter-paramconverterprovider-method-return-type-mismatch)

Comment: So, I am probably doing something wrong, but I cannot figure out what... if I try to add httpRequest to my stateless service, then I am just getting null back.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a provider in your service:

```
@Inject
Provider<RequestVariables> vars
```

And then call get () to get the instance. If you try to get () in a thread outside a request scope context you'll get an exception. I would however try to structure in a way that would not allow this to happen

Comment: I just tested this method and while it seemed fine to call `get()` I am getting a different object each time. I tested this by setting an integer to 42 in my request filter and then getting it in my service. But I get 0 on the integer in my service. So either it is not working, or I'm not setting it properly